# C# Itreator best approach

Tags: c#, iterator

Apart from (IEnumerable Returns GetEnumerator() ,for "foreach" IEnumerble is essential)

almost the following two approaches allow us to iterate over the collection.What is

the advantage of one over another ? (I am not asking the difference between IEnumerable
and IEnumerator).

```
static void Main()
{
    IEnumerator<int> em = MyEnumerator<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
    IEnumerator<int> e = Collection<int>
                        (new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }).GetEnumerator();

    while (em.MoveNext())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(em.Current);
    }

    while (e.MoveNext())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Current);
    }
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

**approach 1**

```
 public static IEnumerator<T> MyEnumerator<T>(T[] vals )

 {
     T[] some = vals;

     foreach (var v in some)
     {
       yield return v;
     }
}
```

**approach 2**

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Collection<T>(T[] vals)
     {
         T[] some = vals;

         foreach (var v in some)
         {
             yield return v;
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is that most API support an imput of `IEnumerable<T>` but not of `IEnumerator<T>`.

You also have to remember to call Reset() when using it while the syntax is more evident in `IEnumerable<T>` (Just call `GetEnumerator` again). Also see the comment of Eric Lipper about reset being a bad idea; if Reset isn't implemented in your `IEnumerator<T>` or is buggy it become a one-time-only enumerator (pretty useless in a lot of cases).

Another difference may be that you could have an `IEnumerable<T>` that could be enumerated from multiple threads at the same time but an `IEnumerator<T>` store one position in the enumerated data (Imagine a `RandomEnumerable` or `RangeEnumerable`).

So the conclusion is that `IEnumerable<T>` is more versatile, but anyway if you have a function returning an `IEnumerator<T>` generating the `IEnumerable<T>` around it is simple.

```
class EnumeratorWrapper<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    Func<IEnumerator<T>> m_generator;
    public EnumeratorWrapper(Func<IEnumerator<T>> generator)
    {
        m_generator = generator;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return m_generator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return m_generator();
    }
}
```

Just for API consistency using `IEnumerable<T>` seem the best solution to me.

But the issue with `Reset()` in `IEnumerator<T>` make it an unusable solution anyway, so `IEnumerable<T>` is the way to go.

Comment: Super duper explanations Thanks

Comment: NEVER call Reset. Reset was a bad idea and is almost always not implemented. If you need to re-start an enumeration, just create a new enumerator.

Comment: Ok so this is one big point against passing around IEnumerator instances, without Reset they are absolutely not viable.

Comment: No, you missed the point. As Eric says, Reset is almost never implemented, so IEnumerable or IEnumerator, in this particular regard, makes no difference. Reset is, as Eric says, a bad idea. Dispose of the old enumerable/enumerator, and create a new one if you need to restart from the beginning. This is always supported, except for destructive iterators.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand your point Lasse. When i said that without Reset-) IEnumerator is useless i wasn't implying that Reset() should be used EVER. I was only speaking about Reset() as a way to bypass the fact that you sometimes need to iterate multiple times over a collection and if you only have an IEnumerator the correct way of doing it (Calling GetEnumerator again) isn't available to you.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong but the only difference is the difference between IEnumerable and IEnumerator and since you specifically said you're not asking the difference, both are a good...